# Date and H:m to unixtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have date without time in unixtime (1497851100 - 2017-06-19) and I have a time in format H:m (13:45, for example). So, how can I get a fully unixtime (timestamp)?

My solution: convert H:m to seconds and add it to unixtime. But maybe there is any other solution withowt .split(':') and etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this? use moment.js (best to deal with time/format/timezone etc) lightweight but really powerful.

There are so many ways you could do it but here I use `moment.unix('1497851100')` to get the date first then add your time by:

```
var dateTime = unixToDate + ' 13:45';
```

Then output the dateTime as `timestamp` using `moment(dateTime).format('X');`

```js
var unixToDate = moment(moment.unix('1497851100')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var dateTime = unixToDate + ' 13:45';
var output = moment(dateTime).format('X');

console.log('unixToDate -->' + unixToDate);
console.log('dateTime   -->' + dateTime);
console.log('output     -->' + output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```